# gdb 8.3.1 on OSX Catalina "not in executable format: file format not recognized"

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb

I try to debug this [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fbhB2NjM62MgkqahuIGHjt13z0AGnfGE)

and got error

```
not in executable format: file format not recognized
```

the 'file' command output

```
canary: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, 
interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=377711637c79e57303ff92f946500aed1b42c73a, for 
GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped`
```

the other answer seem not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ELF binary executable format is standard in Linux and other Unixes.  It is not compatible with macOS, which uses the Mach-O binary format.

Whatever you are attempting to analyze must be recompiled into a Mach-O binary.

Answer (score 0):

macOS Catalina is not supporting 32bit Applications anymore.

I guess this is true for executables too.

See [32-Bit Apps will no longer work on macOS Catalina: Here’s what to do](https://macpaw.com/how-to/32-bit-apps-not-working-catalina)